# fill jtable by sparql results in format string json

Tags: java, json, sparql

I try to fill jtable with json data I tried some solution like

```
String json = "
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 List<User> users = mapper.readValue(json,TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, User.class));
UserTableModel model = new UserTableModel(users);
 tableSkill = new JTable(model);
```

but eclipse give me error and ask me to create class User and User TableModel, so I searched for jar file to import it to resolve this problem but I didn't find it.
anyone can help me, and tell me where is my mistake

Comment: ...is there a Java class User?! And UserTableModel?

Comment: I do not create it. I saw an example where the programer has create class User adapt with json data. but in my case I don't know how that data will be because the data depend on the sparql query result.
I find this (https://st.inf.tu-dresden.de/SalesPoint/v3.3/documentation/javadoc/users/swing/UserTableModel.html) but I do not know how to use it

Comment: But then, how should the code compile **without** the classes?! And if you don'T know the result of the SPARQL query, how do you want to map it to a domain object represented in form of a Java class? I don't get this point. Java has to compile code before you can run it, thus, the class has to exist before you run the SPARQL query. I don't know what you're trying to achieve...representing the result of a SPARQL query as table is trivial given that at least for `SELECT` queries it's basically a resultset which is more or less a set of bindings which can also be seen as a set of rows.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. I will try to create the classes.
may I ask you, how can display the results "not json" of normal "select" in jTable?
I use this function to apply my query  public String runQuery(Model m, String q) {
  Query query = ARQFactory.get().createQuery(model, queryString);
  try(QueryExecution qexec = ARQFactory.get().createQueryExecution(query, model)) {
   ResultSet actualResults = qexec.execSelect();
   ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   ResultSetFormatter.outputAsJSON(os, actualResults);
            return os.toString();

Comment: you have the `ResultSet`. Each `QuerySolution` in it has variable bindings. Create a table model with this

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that avoid you the using of `User` and `User TableModel`:

```
public void runQuerytotable(Model model, String queryString, JTable table,int columns) {
    Query query = ARQFactory.get().createQuery(model, queryString);
    QueryExecution qexec = ARQFactory.get().createQueryExecution(query, model);
    ResultSet rs = qexec.execSelect();
    DefaultTableModel m = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    m.setColumnCount(columns); 
    String[] columnsName = {"URI","label"};
    m.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);
    while(rs.hasNext()) {   
        QuerySolution sol = rs.nextSolution();
        RDFNode URI = sol.get("s"); 
        RDFNode Label = sol.get("o"); 

        m.addRow(new Object[]{URI,Label});
    }
}
```